# Trigger event on Select2 even if the options don't Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to fire an event if I select an option from the select2, but I want it to fire even if the option value is not changed. `My select2 version is 3.4.1 Timestamp: Thu Jun 27 18:02:10 PDT 2013`
I tried a couple of methods.like.

First i tried,

```
$('.myselect').on("change", function(e) { 
  // This function is not triggering if i selected the same option.
});
```

second, I tried,

```
$('.myselect').on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
  // This function triggers alright but it's giving me my previous selected 
  // value(i don't want to use timeout function)
});
```

Comment: Hi, You can either try using 'click' event if you want it to fire every-time regardless of value change.

Comment: @kapilyadav I don't want `click event`, I want anything more of a function from select2 or some tweaks for the experts.

Comment: @JithinRajPR as per the documentation `e.val` gives you the value that is currently clicked.. even if it is the one that is already selected.. I checked the documentation code sample.. http://select2.github.io/select2/#events

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I got the value when I used `e.val` inside `select2-selecting` function. if you want please write the answer combining them, it belongs to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find working solution below for this.

```
$('.myselect').on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
  if(e.val){
    //Do your job
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the **[documentation](http://select2.github.io/select2/#events)** the right way to extract the currently selected value is by using the **e.val** property.

So your code must look like

```
$('.myselect').on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
  alert(e.val); // use this value;
});
```

Comment: a good suggestion but my select2 version is Before 4.0 and in that `select2:select` don't support. I have mentioned this in the Q

Comment: @JithinRajPR updated my answer after looking into the older version documentation..

Answer (score 0):

you can use the select/unselect event and check with conditions

```
$('#myselect').on('select2:unselect', function (evt) {...});
```

Comment: Sorry, my select2 version is Before 4.0 and in that `select2:unselect` don't support. I have mentioned this in the Q